# Paper.js Segment is not defined

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I am modifying a CAD-in-a-browser app i found and i am trying to add some ''add new segment'' functionality. That means that the user can click on a pre-existing curve and add a segment there.

It uses [Paper.j](http://paperjs.org/)s as the canvas library.

The app i found is this: https://github.com/memononen/stylii

This is the code snippet where the functionality is defined:

```
} else if (this.mode == 'insert') {
        if (this.hitResult != null) {
            var location = this.hitResult.location;

            var values = location.curve.getValues();
            var isLinear = location.curve.isLinear();
            var parts = paper.Curve.subdivide(values, location.parameter);
            var left = parts[0];
            var right = parts[1];

            var x = left[6], y = left[7];
            var segment = new Segment(new paper.Point(x, y),
                !isLinear && new paper.Point(left[4] - x, left[5] - y),
                !isLinear && new paper.Point(right[2] - x, right[3] - y));

            var seg = this.hitResult.item.insert(location.index + 1, segment);

            if (!isLinear) {
                seg.previous.handleOut.set(left[2] - left[0], left[3] - left[1]);
                seg.next.handleIn.set(right[4] - right[6], right[5] - right[7]);
            }

            deselectAllPoints();
            seg.selected = true;

            this.hitResult = null;
        }
```

It seems that when i try to use this function i keep getting ''Segment is not defined'' in Chrome Canary, but neither FF works.

The [Paper](http://paperjs.org/) version that Stylii uses : v0.9.15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should have defined the segment upfront in the JS file by doing something like this:

```
var Base = paper.Base,
Segment = paper.segment;
```

Comment: This works with paper.Point and paper.Matrix too. thanks